# Persistent Login with Spotify Web API using MERN stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, spotify

So I have a web app using the MERN stack, and it contains a user database allowing people to register and login to an account. I want to integrate the Spotify API, but I want a user to only to have to connect to Spotify once.

I want it so that a user logs in they have an option to connect to Spotify, and then once they have authenticated it will display some info. I am thinking maybe I need to make a different page and have something set up like

```
if (userIsLoggedIntoSpotify){
   <Link to="/newpage"></Link>
}
```

I also want it so that if a user logs into the app on another computer and they already authenticated they do not have to authenticate again.

I currently have an app that users can register, login and out, and I have a working authentication link to Spotify, I just need a way to tell if users have already authenticated and if so maybe automatically send them to a new page that has the Spotify API already set up and displaying data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do that would be to use the [Authorization Code Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow) with your current user setup. Your app will need to save the Spotify data (`access_token` and `refresh_token`) to your database. One way would be a user would have to first create an account with your app and then they could connect their Spotify account to your app. That way you can save the `access_token` and `refresh_token` on the user object to use later.

When the user logs in later or on a different device, your app would grab the `access_token` and `refresh_token` from your apps database to do whatever you need. As a small note, the `access_token` expires every 60 minutes so you will need the `refresh_token` to request a new `access_token`. When the user logs in at a later time, it will need to check if the `access_token` is expired or not.